# How to solve the issue as when I install the WindowsAzure.Storage Reference from Nu get Manager I got the Exception

Tags: win-universal-app, azure-storage

Currently I am working on Internet of things and Universal Windows Apps, in one my current project I need the reference as WindowsAzure.Storage that's why I am going to nu get manager in that search for WindowsAzure.Storage reference, it having latest version as 6.2.0 then I will start to install this reference, after some time I got the exception like Task was Canceled, see below figure for more information about the Exception.

[image]

Comment: Did you try it again? I tested several times, can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yesterday I tried more than twice but no luck, I tried installing older versions at last version 4.2.1 got installed..... After seeing your reply I tried again It got installed today... Don't know the Issue is but Thanks @grace Feng

Comment: It's good, but what is your project target version? 10240 or 10586?

Comment: OK. I don't know the reason either, but since you can get it work now, just let it be there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicated there was a nuget problem. 
Nuget team addressed the feedback to provide more details in similar errors in the future. At this point, given you found a work around, please move forward and let us know if you get more detailed errors in the future.